# Jquery touch friendly carousel with divs

Tags: jquery, html, carousel

I'm trying to add a carousel on my page but I can't find a good carousel that works with grabbing for smartphone/tablet 
Until now I found `Owl Carousel` and it's great but required the number of items you want on the screen and I don't want it because I would set the item's width and the `padding/margin` on my own. 
Does anyone know something to help me? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Royal Slider is what your looking for : http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/

I worked with it on a projet, it works nice.